# Аналог checkZoomRange при переключении слоя

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не знаю, как без костылей заставить карту проверять доступность масштаба при переключении слоя и зумировать автоматически, если максимальный масштаб нового слоя меньше предыдущего. У метода setType есть настройка checkZoomRange: true, а у самого TypeSelector такой опции нет? Только слушать событие typechange и никак иначе? По идее, это делается в пару строк кода, но просто странным показалось, что нет такой очевидной настройки.

Comment: А где у вас происходит проваливание в недоступный масштаб?

Comment: Свой собственный слой.

layer.getZoomRange = function() {return ymaps.vow.resolve([5, 13]);};

Comment: в TypeSelector этого действительно нет